# 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized

Tags: java, xerces

We upgraded our application to Java8 and Xerces 2.8 version and we are getting the below warning:

```
Warning: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing' is not recognized.
Warning: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
Warning: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser: Property 'http://www.oracle.com/xml/jaxp/properties/entityExpansionLimit' is not recognized.
```

Please let us know why we are getting this warning?

What is the impact of skipping this property/warning?

What will be the value of “entityExpansionLimit” and “accessExternalDTD” if the below warning comes up. Is it the default value or will be null?

Comment: Update formatting

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261771

Answer (score 0):

The application will run with:

```
"-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\WorkAxis\AxisTest\endorsed"
```

and directory `C:\WorkAxis\AxisTest\endorsed` contains files which are:

```
xalan-2.7.2.jar;
serializer-2.7.2.jar; 
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;
```